# Is my IIS configured correctly to handle .NET v3.5?

Tags: .net, iis

It's a windows 2008 R2 sp1 box with iis 7.5. Initially, I saw .net 2.0 is enabled. It's a web server will be shared by multiple application. One application required .net 4.5 which I installed and made sure it set to allowed. Another application is needing .net 3.5 and I dont see that in the list from "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions" menu in the iis. I dont see aspnet_isapi.dll when I click on Add and navigate to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v3.5 folder or the framework64 folder.

Does this mean v3.5 is not really installed on the system but have a folder for it?

Will 4.0 or 4.5 take care of .net 3.5 assemblies?

[image]

Comment: I am sorry to see negative marking. How can I improve this question?

Comment: I think the question title is odd - let me change it for you as I think I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you X0n for making the question more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET v3.5 is not a full framework version itself; it is just a collection of assemblies giving extra functionality for the v2.0.5727 framework, so the `aspnet_isapi.dll` in the v2 folder will handle v3.5. Make sense?

Comment: Thank you very much confirming that. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: That's no problem at all. I think the down votes were just for the unclear title. I changed it for you and countered one of the downs with an up.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help and clarifying it.